# Cloud9 cloud IDE and CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, ide, cloud9-ide

I am currently attempting to get CakePHP running on Cloud9, a cloud based IDE. For those unaware, its a cloud collaboration IDE that intermixes with services such as BitBucket. The site gives sudo rights, and I installed CakePHP using these instructions:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cakephp-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

When I attempt to run my database that I exported from a machine with CakePHP installed, I get the error message "URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server." I attempted to solve the issue using this official guide from CakePHP:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

but no cigar, same error message. Has anyone gotten CakePHP working, or aware of a cloud IDE that is free/low cost like Cloud9 that would support CakePHP?

Comment: Works fine for me out of the box, no need to configure anything. Maybe you should restart from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I got it working just now:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5-intl

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer

./composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app
```

This creates the project in /app by default. Move it to the workspace docroot:

```
mv app/* ./
mv app/.* ./
rm -rf app
```

Then the default url rewriting worked as expected. HTH